# "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" when trying to install Windows on my late 2009 iMac

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, mac

OS X is 10.6.3. I create the partition with Boot Camp, insert the Windows 7 DVD, reboot, and that's what I get. I'm at loss.

When I press alt/option to bring up the boot disk selection screen, the Boot Camp partition isn't an option. I don't know if this is normal or an indication something's not quite right.

Comment: I ran into this too - you get when burning the disc from MacOS - burn it using the Burn tool mentioned above, or use a windows ISO burning program.

Answer (score -1):

It was the disc format. The Finder burns discs in HFS+. I got [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/) and burnt it in UDF and it worked.

Comment: You've managed to create a duplicate account (if you registered that is). I suspect you've used a different e-mail address this time. E-mail team@superuser.com to ask them to merge the accounts.